# Crystal Report cross-tabs w/o summary

Tags: crystal-reports, report, crosstab

I've been fighting this issue for quite a while now and I need some help. I'm creating reports of chemical compliance . As a part I need to insert a grid that lists chemical element, expected minimum and maximum values and measured value. The data table in db looks like this

CertSerialNumber    Element IsSpecificationMember   ResultValue

10110   C   1   0.04

10110   C   1   0.06

10110   C   0   0.06

10110   Mn  1   0.06

10110   Mn  1   0.06

10110   Mn  0   0.06

10110   P   1   0.006

10110   P   1   0.006

10110   P   0   0.006

10110   S   1   0.009

10110   S   1   0.009

10110   S   0   0.008

There is maximum of 14 elements listed and each element can have 2 or 3 records (1 or to for spec min and max or just max) and 1 for actual reading. Boolean indicateds if record contains spec and larger of the values with true record is max spec, lesser is min value. In case there is only one record with true in IsSpecificationMember - it is a max.

I have a problem grouping items correctly so it gets displayed correctly. The first column should show IsSpec column, second col should show particle name and rows should read values for each value sorted by IsSpec boolean.
However, cr wants to add right and bottom summaries. It is also listing all the values in an untitled column and none under elements' names.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To the extent I understand your issue, You are not grouping correctly.

First group by Isspec and then by particle now place both the group headers on group header 2.

Take the result value and summarize and place it below which ever column you wish to see.